# How to set a global scale factor for all figures (for consistent sizing) with manual override?

Tags: graphics, scaling, preamble, includegraphics

In my PhD thesis in engineering, I expect to have approximately hundred plots which are vector graphics (in PDF format) created *close* to the final size (but not exactly).

I'd like to declare a global size in the preamble, say 75% of the textwidth. Then I can simply use `\includegraphics{filename.pdf}` for each figure, without worrying about the `[scale=xx]` option. Later, if one needs to tweak figure sizes to prevent awkward paginations, one can simply change this to (say) 70%. Then, all figures would obey this setting, thereby helping to maintain consistency in the document.

I have used the following setting in the preamble

> \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.75\textwidth}  % default width of graphics

However, now I lost **manual control** for individual figures, i.e. Latex does not obey the `[scale=xx]` option anymore. I have a couple of illustrations that do not belong to this global paradigm, and need to scale just these.

Is there some way achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Can you manually overwrite the scaling with `[width=.9\textwidth]`?

Comment: @samcarter Yes. But this is not what I want. It also skews the figure making it appear squashed or elongated. I would like to scale uniformly the width and height.

Comment: Specifying width alone will keep the aspect ratio intact. No squashing happens unless you specify both width and height with different ratios from the original width and height. I've rarely used scale instead of width.

Comment: check the adjustbox package. Imho it has code for this.

Comment: Unless you are explicitly setting the height as well, this should not distort the aspect ratio. Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Yes. You guys are correct. I was also using the ```height=``` setting. I thought that using ```width``` alone is not sufficient to fully quantify the size. But I just took a look at the ```graphicx``` documentation, and yes, this works fine.  It is surprising that the latex kernel does not do this by default. Consistency is one of the strong points of latex, and if one has vector graphs of data-points, then setting a global figure size with local override should be the default behaviour and built right into the documentclass or somewhere fundamental.

Comment: @samcarter I just summarised the comments as an answer. There are no similiar questions atleast upon a first-pass search. It might be useful for others googling and landing here.

Comment: Why not just create a macro for the scale factor?  [scale={\myscale}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is now solved thanks to the community here.

Even though the `[scale=xx]` option for `\includegraphics` does not work anymore (I don't know why?) after setting `\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.75\textwidth}` in the preamble, the `[width=xx]` option works.

Thus, one can get consistent sizing of figures in the document, and yet retain manual control for individual figures. Note that this question and answer are largely applicable for vector graphics sizes. Otherwise, arbitrary scaling of raster images would lead to pixelisation.

PS: IMHO, this feature should be offered at a more fundamental level, perhaps as an option to the `graphicx` package.